# MySQL - Group by duplicated value in table to do count and save output in another table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a MySQL table called table1 which holds values of devices that are on a page. The page pings back a script EVERY 2 SECOND that fills out the table.

The table structure is as follows:

```
id
timestamp
domain
ip 
useragent
```

Every device has a unique IP address. In the table, I have multiple entries belonging to the same device.

I want to be able to count the number of records grouped by IP address and save this in a new table (called table2) which has the following structure:

```
id
ip
domain
useragent
count
```

In both table1 and table 2, id is auto-increment.

So far, I have come up with:

```
SELECT   ip, COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY ip; HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How do I save the output into table2?

Comment: How about the devices with only one entry, with count =1 ? will it be written to table2?

Comment: @DylanSu, sounds like OP wants only the dupe records to be written to another table. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insert into .. select from` construct

```
insert into table2(ip,
domain,
useragent,
`count`)
select ip,
domain,
useragent,
count(*) as `count`
from table1
group by ip
having `count` > 1;
```